# Cannot see HTML div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am starting to build a website for the first time but I am having trouble with the .Main div. I am giving it a `background-color: orange;` on the CSS but I cannot see it anywhere. When using the inspector, I can see that it is positioned on 1440 x 0. Can someone help with this, please?

This is my code so far...

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor')
const main = document.querySelector('.Main');

let cursorSize = 50;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  
    cursor.style.left = `${event.clientX - cursorSize / 2}px`;
    cursor.style.top = `${event.clientY - cursorSize / 2}px`;

    const isSelectable = event.target.tagName === 'P' || event.target.tagName === 'H2';
    if (isSelectable) {
        cursor.classList.add('hide'); // Hide the cursor when mouse is over text or text is selected
        main.classList.add('cursor-text');
    } else {
        cursor.classList.remove('hide'); // Show the cursor when mouse is not over text and no text is selected
        main.classList.remove('cursor-text');
    }
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    cursorSize = 20;
    pointerStyle(event, cursorSize)
});
  
document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
    cursorSize = 50;
    pointerStyle(event, cursorSize)
});

let pointerStyle = (event, size) => {
    let newX = event.clientX - size / 2;
    let newY = event.clientY - size / 2;
    
    cursor.style.width = `${size}px`;
    cursor.style.height = `${size}px`;
    cursor.style.left = `${newX}px`;
    cursor.style.top = `${newY}px`;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.Main{
    cursor: none;
    background-color: orange;
}

.cursor{ 
    position: absolute;  
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    background-color: #84E6BC;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
} 

.cursor.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.cursor-text {
    cursor: text;
}

.banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
  
.title {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
  
.subheading {
    font-size: var(--p-size);
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
  
.smiley {
    fill: #84E6BC;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main">
    <div class="banner">
        <h2 class="title">Thank you!</h2>
        <p class="subheading">I really appreciate you contacting me. I will be in touch shortly.</p>
        <svg class="smiley" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M8 16A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zM4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM10 8c-.552 0-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5S10.552 8 10 8z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"positioned on 1440 x 0"_... this looks more like dimensions. If the element has 0 height, it won't be visible. You should add some content that is part of its normal layout flow and _not_ [fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed)

Comment: do you need the main div specifically to be orange, or would it work if the body itself is orange instead of that div

Comment: I just need the main to be orange

Comment: @Philisonstrike there is content inside the Main section

Comment: The `.banner` class has a `position: fixed` and `.cursor` has `position: absolute;`. This means that both these elements breaks out of the flow of the document and therefor won't intrinsicly size `.Main`. So basically, `.Main` doesn't know *how high* it should be, so it defaults to `0px`. If you'd add an element to `.Main` that has either `position: relative` or `position: static` - not setting the `position` property will have it default to `static` - , then `.Main` will stretch to accommodate the elements and show its color.

Comment: The `head` tag is missing from your example. Not sure if that's related to the issue though.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier could you give me an example with the code provided please? Your explanation makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element inside of main is `position: fixed` which means it sticks to the screen at the position you specify regardless of scrolling.  Doing this takes it out of the normal "flow" of elements. Because it's out of the normal flow, it collapses to `0px` height since it has nothing inside it actually taking up space.

See the below code.  I've commented out the positioning code and just used `margin: 0 auto` to horizontally center the `.Banner` element

FYI: not related to your question but for the cursor you will want to change to that from `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` - otherwise when you scroll down the page the positioning will not match the actual cursor position.

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor')
const main = document.querySelector('.Main');

let cursorSize = 50;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  
    cursor.style.left = `${event.clientX - cursorSize / 2}px`;
    cursor.style.top = `${event.clientY - cursorSize / 2}px`;

    const isSelectable = event.target.tagName === 'P' || event.target.tagName === 'H2';
    if (isSelectable) {
        cursor.classList.add('hide'); // Hide the cursor when mouse is over text or text is selected
        main.classList.add('cursor-text');
    } else {
        cursor.classList.remove('hide'); // Show the cursor when mouse is not over text and no text is selected
        main.classList.remove('cursor-text');
    }
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    cursorSize = 20;
    pointerStyle(event, cursorSize)
});
  
document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
    cursorSize = 50;
    pointerStyle(event, cursorSize)
});

let pointerStyle = (event, size) => {
    let newX = event.clientX - size / 2;
    let newY = event.clientY - size / 2;
    
    cursor.style.width = `${size}px`;
    cursor.style.height = `${size}px`;
    cursor.style.left = `${newX}px`;
    cursor.style.top = `${newY}px`;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.Main{
    cursor: none;
    background-color: orange;
}

.cursor{ 
    position: absolute;  
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    background-color: #84E6BC;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
} 

.cursor.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.cursor-text {
    cursor: text;
}

.banner {
    /*position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
    margin: 0 auto; /* <-- Added this to horizintally center this element*/
    width: 60%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
  
.title {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
  
.subheading {
    font-size: var(--p-size);
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
  
.smiley {
    fill: #84E6BC;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main">
    <div class="banner">
        <h2 class="title">Thank you!</h2>
        <p class="subheading">I really appreciate you contacting me. I will be in touch shortly.</p>
        <svg class="smiley" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M8 16A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zM4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM10 8c-.552 0-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5S10.552 8 10 8z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```